# JavaScript Search And Highlight Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing a highlight feature for a live search in JavaScript/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247368/implementing-a-highlight-feature-for-a-live-search-in-javascript-jquery)

Assume I have a div:

```
<div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
```

Basically I want to do a search via javascript and then highlight the results. So, assume the search query is `magna aliqua`. I am doing the following:

```
$("#content:contains('magna aliqua')").addClass("highlight");
```

This works, but applies the highlight class to the entire div `content`. What I want is to only highlight the exact words magna aliqua, which means I somehow have to wrap the text in a tag and then apply the highlight class on that new tag.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Removing my answer: there is a way but its a bad example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Q2GcK/ (courtesy@FelixKling - That's a relatively bad example. It would also try to replace the words in HTML attributes and would destroy any event handler which has been bound to any element inside element."

Comment: You can also have a look at [my plugin here](https://github.com/fkling/jquery_playground/blob/master/jquery_text_highlight.js). It's not finished, but it works for highlighting simple text.

Answer (score 0):

Great plugin `highlight`. This fork supports regex searches.

http://beatgates.blogspot.com/2011/07/extend-jqueryhighlight-to-highlight.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
word = 'magna aliqua'
var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
var repl = '<span class="myClass">' + word + '</span>';

var element = $("#content:contains(word)");
element.html(element.html().replace(rgxp, repl));
```

Comment: That's a relatively bad example. It would also try to replace the words in HTML attributes and would destroy any event handler which has been bound to any element inside `element`.