# Highlight search keywords result

Tags: javascript, search, highlight, keyword

I am using the below search function in my table. I need to highlight any results matching with the keywords in the search input in the table. I am not sure how to add the scripting in. Kindly assist me on this as I am very new to Jscripting and still learning.

```
window.tableSearch = {};

tableSearch.init = function () {
  this.Rows = document.getElementById('data').getElementsByTagName('TR');
  this.RowsLength = tableSearch.Rows.length;
  this.RowsText = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tableSearch.RowsLength; i++) {
    this.RowsText[i] = (tableSearch.Rows[i].innerText) ? tableSearch.Rows[i].innerText.toUpperCase() : tableSearch.Rows[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
  }
}

tableSearch.runSearch = function () {
  this.Term = document.getElementById('textBoxSearch').value.toUpperCase();
  for (var i = 0, row; row = this.Rows[i], rowText = this.RowsText[i]; i++) {
    row.style.display = ((rowText.indexOf(this.Term) != -1) || this.Term === '') ? '' : 'none';
  }
}

tableSearch.search = function (e) {
  var keycode;
  if (window.event) {
    keycode = window.event.keyCode;
  } else if (e) {
    keycode = e.which;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  if (keycode == 13) {
    tableSearch.runSearch();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They people in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247368/implementing-a-highlight-feature-for-a-live-search-in-javascript-jquery) thread used a [jQuery pluging](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) to highlight the search string.

```
var words = "keyword1,keyword2,keyword3";
var keywords = words.split(',');
for(var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    $(selector).highlight($.trim(keywords[i]));
}
```

Is that something you could implement in your code as well?